# to be + verb+ED or verb+ING

Tags: verbs, future-tense

Which one is the correct usage in the following examples? Are they both correct?

1. The carrots need **to be chopped**.

   The carrots need **chopping**.

1. The bill needs **to be paid**.

   The bill needs **paying**.

1. Do you want **to be picked** up?

   Do you want **picking** up?

If this is correct grammatical structure could someone help classify the tenses of these, i.e are they both *future tense*?

I would tend to use the first example using *to be verb+ED*. Is the second case correct too or is this a form of slang?

Comment: I would prefer version (1) for all three, but, for the first two, version (2) sounds acceptable in conversation. The last one sounds "off", though – that question needs fixing. Perhaps it sounds worse because of the phrasal verb?

Comment: I'd say they are all okay, so it's a free choice. English does not have a future tense, so **no** to that question. All your examples are present tense ("need" is a **present tense** lexical verb and "do" is a present tense auxiliary verb).

Answer (score 1):

As a native British English speaker, the second option sounds more natural to me for all three examples, but all your sentences are perfectly grammatical.